What exactly might be 変化 and how should I understand 変化を観察したい in the following sentence for it to make sense?
I came across the following sentence in my Japanese textbook. It is provided without any further context, and it is one of the four given example sentences to understand the grammar points ～に伴って ・ ～とともに:

地球の温暖化に伴うさまざまな変化を観察したいと思っている。

Which I translated as:

Along with the global warming, I think I'd like to observe several changes.

As far as I understand it correctly, 観察 means "observation", rather than just "seeing", which makes me think that 変化を観察 naturally refers to observing changes in the nature, environtment, society, etc. triggered or caused by the global warming. On the other hand, this interpretation doesn't make complete sense to me because such changes would probably be negative (more natural disasters, extremer climates, etc.), so why would anyone "think they'd like to observe" such negative changes?
To me, something more factual rather than 観察したい would make more sense:

地球の温暖化に伴うさまざまな変化を観察するでしょう。


地球の温暖化に伴うさまざまな変化を観察するに違いない。


地球の温暖化に伴うさまざまな変化を観察していくと思う。

Is it possible that 変化を観察 is here referring to a change of policies or regulations, or any other change not inherently negative, or what am I missing here?

Wouldn't this be a natural thing for a climate scientist to say, for example?

地球の温暖化に伴う is a relative clause that modifies 変化, so the sentence should be translated like "I want to observe various changes associated with global warming".

@user3856370 this finally clicked with me, that as a scientist, you probably wouldn't like to see such negative changes, but you would want to observe (and analyze and understand) them as much as possible.

Gathering @user3856370 and @naruto's thoughts expressed in the comments to my question, I understood that my attempted translation was wrong, and the appropriate translation should be:

I'd like I want to observe various changes associated with global warming.

In this context, translating ~たい as "to want to ~" rather than "to like to ~" would have probably saved me the headache in the first place.

The sentence seems to implicitly take the position that these changes are inevitable, and states that they want to actively observe them (for example, properly measuring and recording), rather than passively ignoring/accepting them.　Also, the changes can be more trivial (and less negative) such as earlier flowering of cherry blossom, less snowfall etc...
